# Azure custom script extension stuck. not able to rerun or delete extension

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I was trying to run a custom script on my scaleset vm due to the wrong location of the sh file the exeuction failed. but after that when I try to remove (az vmss extension delete) or rerun(az vmss extension set )  the custom script with correct url I keep getting the same error. It is stuck. How do I fix it.

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
>   249a034f-76e2-4b0d-beb2-e9c6577623d1. VM has reported a failure when
>   processing extension 'customScript'. Error message: "Enable failed:
>   processing file downloads failed: failed to download file[0]: failed
>   to download file: http request failed: Get
>   https://wrongurl.blob.core.windows.net/script/deploytemp.sh: dial tcp:
>   lookup wrongurl.blob.core.windows.net on 164.33.122.16:53: no such
>   host".

Answer (score 0):

Delete the instance and rebuild it!

It might not be the answer to delete the instance and rebuilding it, but applications on VMSS by nature should be resilient enough to let you do so.

Also, I'm curious if auto-healing/remediation helps you on this, I know that it does not reinstall the extension tough.